# Pop up calendar hides the behind dropdown list in IE 9 browser

Tags: css

When calendar Pop up calendar it disappear behind dropdown list in IE 9 browser. In other browser its working fine. Can anyone let me know what could be the reason and what is the fix. PSA images

[image: before clicking the calendar]

[image: when calendar pop up DDL disappears]

and below is the CSS i have used.

```
select {
    border: 1px solid #859099;
}

.orderTracking\.home .searchTable .statusSelect, .dateSelectionWrapper {
    padding-right: 45px;
}
```

and the HTML is

```
<table id="searchTable"
       class="searchTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="searchCell">
                <div class="statusSelect">
                    <h3 class="tableheader">Status:</h3>
                    <select name="orderStatus">
                        <option value=""
                                selected="">All</option>
                        <option value="backOrder">BackOrdered</option>
                        <option value="reserved">Reserved</option>
                        <option value="confirmed">Picking</option>
                        <option value="cancelled">Cancelled</option>
                        <option value="complete">Complete</option>
                        <option value="review">Under Review</option>
                        <option value="approved">Approved</option>
                        <option value="demand">Demand</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="dateSelectionWrapper startDay">
                    <h3 class="tableheader">Date From:</h3>
                    <div class="dateFieldsWrapper">
                        <input type="Text"
                               name="startMonth"
                               class="startMonth"
                               value="8"
                               readonly=""
                               dir="rtl"
                               size="1">/
                            <input type="Text"
                                   name="startDay"
                                   class="startDay"
                                   value="17"
                                   readonly=""
                                   dir="rtl"
                                   size="1">/
                                <input type="Text"
                                       name="startYear"
                                       class="startYear"
                                       value="2015"
                                       readonly=""
                                       dir="rtl"
                                       size="1">
                    </div>
                    <img class="calendarTrigger"
                         id="f_trigger_c"
                         title="Calendar"
                         src="images/Icon-Calendar.png"
                         style="cursor: pointer;">
                </div>
                <div class="dateSelectionWrapper endDay">
                    <h3 class="tableheader">Date To:</h3>
                    <div class="dateFieldsWrapper">
                        <input type="Text"
                               name="endMonth"
                               class="endMonth"
                               value="9"
                               readonly=""
                               dir="rtl"
                               size="1">/
                            <input type="Text"
                                   name="endDay"
                                   class="endDay"
                                   value="17"
                                   readonly=""
                                   dir="rtl"
                                   size="1">/
                                <input type="Text"
                                       name="endYear"
                                       class="endYear"
                                       value="2015"
                                       readonly=""
                                       dir="rtl"
                                       size="1">
                    </div>
                    <img class="calendarTrigger"
                         id="f_trigger_c1"
                         title="Calendar"
                         src="images/Icon-Calendar.png"
                         style="cursor: pointer;">
                </div>
                <div class="searchBtnCell">
                    <input class="searchBtn"
                           tabindex="4"
                           type="submit"
                           value="Search">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. In IE9 and before `<select>` elements were rendered as OS-level dropdown controls. These were therefore always drawn on top, ignoring CSS layers and Z-indexing.

The only workaround for this is to change your design so it cannot occur, or temporarily hiding all `select` elements while a popup is active. The last solution was actually quite common when IE6-9 were still prevalent.